# How to reconcile number of factors found with parallel factor analysis and network plotting in exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to apply exploratory factor analysis and I got the following output when using  parallel factor analysis (`fa.parallel` of the R package `psych`):

```
Call: psych::fa.parallel(x = df, fa = "pc", n.iter = 500, ylabel = "Eigenvalues", 
    quant = 0.5)
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  NA  and the number of components =  3
```

When using the `Very Simple Structure` approach (function `VSS`) I get:

```
Very Simple Structure
Call: vss(x = x, n = n, rotate = rotate, diagonal = diagonal, fm = fm, 
    n.obs = n.obs, plot = plot, title = title, use = use, cor = cor)
VSS complexity 1 achieves a maximimum of 0.92  with  1  factors
VSS complexity 2 achieves a maximimum of 0.97  with  3  factors

The Velicer MAP achieves a minimum of 0.04  with  6  factors
```

Thus, I reckon that the exploratory factor analysis should be conducted with 3-6 variables.

With 3 factors, I get (with `fa.diagram`):

[image]

With 6 factors:

[image]

But using the Triangulated Maximally Filtered Graph generated by the package EGAnet, I get 5 factors:

[image]

Which is then reflected by the fa.diagram.

The question is: what factor to choose? Would the latter be the best? After all, it is within 3 and 6... Is there a better justification?

Thank you